# nose.tools.nontrivial.TimeExpired: Time limit (2) exceeded

Tags: python, numpy, performance, for-loop

How do I improve the performance of the following code? It raised `nose.tools.nontrivial.TimeExpired: Time limit (2) exceeded` error.

```
import numpy as np

def mutual_information(arr):
    p_i = np.sum(arr, axis=1)
    p_j = np.sum(arr, axis=0)
    p = np.sum(arr)

    mi = 0
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
            if arr[i, j] != 0:
                mi += arr[i, j] * np.log(arr[i, j] / (p_i[i] * p_j[j]))
    mi /= p

    return mi
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 60, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 676, in run
    self._callTestMethod(testMethod)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 633, in _callTestMethod
    method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nose/tools/nontrivial.py", line 100, in newfunc
    raise TimeExpired("Time limit (%s) exceeded" % limit)
nose.tools.nontrivial.TimeExpired: Time limit (2) exceeded
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Can you give a minimal example?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same much more efficiently using numpy's vectorized operations with [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
def mutual_information(arr):
    return (arr * 
            np.log(arr / arr.sum(1)[:, None] / arr.sum(0)[None, :], out=np.zeros_like(arr, dtype=float), where=arr != 0)
           ).sum() / arr.sum()
```

For a 1000 elements array this is more than 100 times faster than the loop solution.